# Does LM324 require regulated rails voltages?

Tags: integrated-circuit

To dual power an [LM324](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf), if we need to make our own split supply from a DC power source such as this one below:

[image]
(taken from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/332708/how-to-make-a-split-supply-from-a-single-supply-by-using-two-linear-regulators-l) question)

do we need to regulate the rail powers Vee and Vcc for LM324?

I have a 5V or 9V or 12V or 15V DC supply to obtain split power rails as +/-12V or +/-15V.

And I'm trying to find a simple solution to power LM324 with +/-12V or +/-15V. I might use [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/isolated-dc-dc-converters/2233647/) DC-DC converter but I'm afraid of the high switching noise. Do I need to obtain regulated power rails for this IC? What can be the easy and nosewise quiet solution?

Comment: If you need a split rail supply you need a mid-rail voltage that is reliable. The one above has problems if the current taken from the positive rail is more than that taken into the negative rail.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for feedback. I was thinking to use the DC-DC converter to obtain split supply. But my concern its noise. Is it something no go for audio ICs?

Comment: The Dc-DC converter you linked works at 260 kHz (much higher frequency than audio).

Comment: Read its datasheet, noting the "PSRR" or Power Supply Rejection Ratio figure. Multiply this by the noise on your PSU. If the resulting voltage doesn't meet your noise spec, you need cleaner supplies.

Comment: LM324 doesn't need much power (?). So I would use some L-C filters to try or really an active ground.